# If the series $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k$ converges then $a_k$ converges to 0.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

If the series $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k$ converges then $a_k$ converges to 0.

How to prove this theorem?

Comment: Please, try to make the title of your question more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 3):

Hint: you have to *really* understand the definition of "convergent series" to take advantage of the following:

$$S_n:=\sum_{k=1}^na_k\implies a_n=S_n-S_{n-1}\;\;\ldots\ldots$$